# Getting server data with AJAX in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying make an AJAX call to get server data into my React Components.

I'm unable to display it with React. I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I've done research http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/ and [reactjs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107869/reactjs-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined) ;however, I'm not sure how to map it to my react component.

Here is my code below:

```
var items;
$.get("http://localhost:3000/getProducts", function( data ) {
   items = data;
   this.state.items = data;
});

/*React Code Below */
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
      return { items: [] }
   },
   render: function() {
      var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
         return (
            <div className='brick'>
               <div>
                  <a target='_blank' href={item.productURL}><img src={item.imageURL}/></a>
                  <p className='itemName'>Short Sleeve Oxford Dress Shirt, White, Large</p>
                  <p className='storeName'>Nike Factory Store</p>
                  <img className='foundPicture' src='../images/rohit.png'/>
               </div>
            </div>
         );
      });

      return (
         <div>
            {listItems}
         </div>
      );
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />,             
   document.getElementById('clothing-content'));
```

My JSON array with item properties are valid:

Here is the array below:

```
[ { _id: 584d1e36a609b545b37611ac,
    imageURL: 'http://ih1.redbubble.net/image.252113981.3904/ra,unisex_tshirt,x1350,fafafa:ca443f4786,front-c,30,60,940,730-bg,f8f8f8.u2.jpg',
    productName: 'Drake',
    productType: 'T-Shirts & Hoodies',
    price: '$29.97',
    productURL: 'http://www.redbubble.com/people/misfitapparel/works/22923904-drake?grid_pos=6&p=t-shirt',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Why is this error occurring? And how should it be implemented?

Comment: @AndyRay Should my get request be in my initial state function?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is **asynchronous**. Your get function callback does not block program flow, it executes at a later time. The rest of your code will continue to execute. You're sending an AJAX request asynchronously, then you're rendering a react component with an undefined variable. Then, at a later time, the get request will finish and your data will be populated, but this is long after rendering has completed.

The simplest solution here is to only render the component once your AJAX request has finished:

```
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <div className='brick'>
                <div>
                    <a target='_blank' href={item.productURL}><img src={item.imageURL}/></a>
                    <p className='itemName'>Short Sleeve Oxford Dress Shirt, White, Large</p>
                    <p className='storeName'>Nike Factory Store</p>
                    <img className='foundPicture' src='../images/rohit.png'/>
                </div>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {listItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

$.get("http://localhost:3000/getProducts", function( data ) {
    ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={data} />,
        document.getElementById('clothing-content'));
});
```

A better solution, depending on your needs, is probably to do the AJAX request in a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, and store the result in state instead of props.

Comment: Can you expand on what are the advantages of doing the request in the componentDidMount lifecycle method?

Comment: Hmm weird, I'm still getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined error

Comment: Log `data` in the get callback to make sure it's populated.

Comment: well I'm actually not getting the TypeError, but it looks like it's not populated.

Comment: do I have to bind it? re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720791/fetched-data-from-ajax-in-component-is-not-rendering-in-react?rq=1

Comment: No. Are you using the code I posted, with the render function **inside** the get callback?

Comment: Here's a simple example using a fake data endpoint https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/64918/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130364/discussion-between-rohit-tigga-and-andy-ray).

Answer (score 0):

```
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
      return { items: this.props.items || [] }
   },
   componentWillMount: function() {
     console.log("componentWillMount()")
     $.get("http://localhost:3000/getProducts", function( data ) {
         this.setState({ items : data })
         console.log(data,"data is here");
      }.bind(this));
   },
   render: function() {
      var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
         return (
            <ListItem item={item}/>
         );
      });

      return (
         <div>
             {listItems}
         </div>
      );
   }
});
/* make the items stateless */
var ListItem = function(props) {
     return (
         <div className='brick' key={props.item._id}>
         <div>
             <a target='_blank' href={props.item.productURL}><img src={props.item.imageURL}/></a>
             <p className='itemName'>Short Sleeve Oxford Dress Shirt, White, Large</p>
             <p className='storeName'>Nike Factory Store</p>
             <img className='foundPicture' src='../images/rohit.png'/>
         </div>
         </div>
     );
}
var data = []
ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={data} />, document.getElementById('clothing-content'));
```

I had to bind the data and use componentWillMount.